Launch.json using template project for .net
I am creating a project template for .NET, but I would like to add the creation of the launch.json file for Visual Studio Code to this template.
The idea is to make developers' work easier since generating this file can be complex.
Is there a way to add an action to create this launch.json file? I tried creating a directory in the solution with this file and just moving it, but I couldn't find how to add this action in template.json.
